# how to define function with variable arguments in python - there is 'but'

Tags: python

I am going to define a function which takes a variable number of strings and examines each string and replaces `/` with `-`. and then return them back. (here is my logic problem - return what?)

```
def replace_all_slash(**many):
    for i in many:
        i = i.replace('/','-')
    return many
```

is it correct? how can i recollect the strings as separate strings again?

example call:

```
 allwords = replace_all_slash(word1,word2,word3)
```

but i need `allwords` to be separate strings as they were before calling the function. how to do this?

i hope i am clear to understand

Comment: word1,word2,word3 = replace_all_slash(word1,word2,word3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `*args` (one star) not `**args`:

```
>>> def replace_all_slash(*words):
   return [word.replace("/", "-") for word in words]

>>> word1 = "foo/"
>>> word2 = "bar"
>>> word3 = "ba/zz"
>>> replace_all_slash(word1, word2, word3)
['foo-', 'bar', 'ba-zz']
```

Then, to re-assign them into the same variables, use the assignment unpacking syntax:

```
>>> word1
'foo/'
>>> word2
'bar'
>>> word3
'ba/zz'
>>> word1, word2, word3 = replace_all_slash(word1, word2, word3)
>>> word1
'foo-'
>>> word2
'bar'
>>> word3
'ba-zz'
```

Comment: Hopefully the OP doesn't really have variable1, variable2, variable3, etc.  Such naming is a code-smell indicating he needs a list.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Truly, yet who knows the details of his endeavors? Not I. As such I will refrain from judging.

Answer (score 1):

Solution one: create a new list and append that that:

```
def replace_all_slash(*many):
    result = []
    for i in many:
        result.append(i.replace('/','-'))
    return result
```

Solution two using a list comprehension:

```
def replace_all_slash(*many):
    return [i.replace('/','-') for i in many]
```

Comment: cool, but how do i disassemble list to separate former strings?

Comment: This will give an error if called without keyword arguments.  For positional arguments replace `**many` with `*many`.

Comment: This doesn't work because **many is a dict holding key=value arguments. Perhaps *many is intended?

Comment: `def replace_all_slash(*many): return [s.replace('/','-') for s in many]`

Comment: @doniyor: `*` in front of the argument returns a list of all unmatched positional arguments.  `**` in front of the argument returns a list of all unmatched keyword arguments.

Comment: Sorry, should have been 1 star indeed. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your function:

```
def replace_all_slash(*args):
    return [s.replace('/','-') for s in args]
```

and you can call it this way:

```
w1,w2,w3 = replace_all_slash("AA/","BB/", "CC/")
```

Comment: You may want to change the name of your loop variable to `s`.  `i` often indicates an loop counter.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - good point but (a) I like "i" a lot :-) (b) There are so few loop counters in my Python code! Anyway, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Disassembling the arguments in the calling code requires variables for each string.

```
word1,word2,word3 = replace_all_slash(word1,word2,word3)
```